Retrieve cell of a DataFrame Enum column as an Enum
I have a DataFrame in which several columns are defined as Enums. When I retrieve a cell in an Enum column, the value is returned as a string. How do I retrieve the value as an Enum? Shown below is a small repro:
import polars as pl


flags: pl.Enum = pl.Enum(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
df: pl.DataFrame = pl.DataFrame(data={"x": ["foo", "bar", "baz"]}, schema_overrides={"x": flags})
df.dtypes
# Returns [Enum(categories=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])]
type(df[0, "x"])
# Returns str instead of Enum
# Series.to_list() returns list of str instead of list of Enum
[type(t) for t in df[:, "x"].to_list()]
# Returns [str, str, str]


what kind of output do you expect actually?

I thought I was quite clear. I am expecting to retrieve cells of Enum columns as Enums. Unfortunately, they are being returned as strings.

Are you saying you expect the result to be mapped to a stdlib enum.Enum type? https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

No. I expect the DataFrame cell to be returned as a Polars.Enum object. In my example, that would be the type flags which I defined.

But when you materialize a value in Python, there is no Polars type anymore. e.g. type(pl.select(pl.date(2020, 1, 1)).item()) gives you a datetime.time object.

I wasn't aware of that. In that case the returned string type make sense.

The Enum type currently does not return an Enum instance when accessing a cell or converting the series to a list. The value is returned as a string. To get the value as an Enum type  you can manually map the string values back to their corresponding Enum instances. Here a slightly more elaborate example:
import polars as pl
from enum import Enum

class Status(Enum):
    active = "active"
    inactive = "inactive"
    pending = "pending"

class Priority(Enum):
    low = "low"
    medium = "medium"
    high = "high"

status_enum = pl.Enum(["active", "inactive", "pending"])
priority_enum = pl.Enum(["low", "medium", "high"])

df = pl.DataFrame(
    data={
        "status": ["active", "inactive", "pending", "active"],
        "priority": ["low", "high", "medium", "low"],
    },
    schema_overrides={
        "status": status_enum,
        "priority": priority_enum,
    }
)

single_cell_enum = Status(df[0, "status"])

status_enum_list = [Status(value) for value in df[:, "status"].to_list()]

priority_enum_list = [Priority(value) for value in df[:, "priority"].to_list()]

print(single_cell_enum)
print(status_enum_list)
print(priority_enum_list)

Which gives
Status.active
[<Status.active: 'active'>, <Status.inactive: 'inactive'>, <Status.pending: 'pending'>, <Status.active: 'active'>]
[<Priority.low: 'low'>, <Priority.high: 'high'>, <Priority.medium: 'medium'>, <Priority.low: 'low'>]

Edit: Using ploar.Enum
import polars as pl

status_enum = pl.Categorical  
priority_enum = pl.Categorical

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "status": ["active", "inactive", "pending", "active"],
        "priority": ["low", "high", "medium", "low"],
    }
).with_columns(
    [
        pl.col("status").cast(status_enum),
        pl.col("priority").cast(priority_enum),
    ]
)

single_cell_enum = df[0, "status"]  

status_enum_list = df["status"].to_list()
priority_enum_list = df["priority"].to_list()

print(f"Single Cell Enum: {single_cell_enum}")
print(f"Status Enum List: {status_enum_list}")
print(f"Priority Enum List: {priority_enum_list}")

which gives
Single Cell Enum: active
Status Enum List: ['active', 'inactive', 'pending', 'active']
Priority Enum List: ['low', 'high', 'medium', 'low']


In my example, the fields were polars.Enum. Your example uses enum.Enum fields. They are not the same.

@scorpio I edited my answer: Does that work for you?
